# Java add Classpaths at runtime

Tags: java, runtime, classpath

There are many answers to this question in the stackoverflow?
But the most cast the `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()` to URLClassLoader and this works anymore.

The classes must be found by the systemclassloader.

Is there an another solution?
  - without restarting the jar
  - without creating a own classloader (In this case I must replace the systemclassloader with my own)

The missing classes/jars must be added at the moment only on startup and I didn't want to add these in the manifest with "Classpath".
I found the Java Agent with the premain-Method. This can also work great, but in this case I want to start the premain method without calling "java -javaagent:... -jar ..."

Currently I restart my programm at the beginning with the missing classpaths:

```
public class LibLoader {
    protected static List<File> files = new LinkedList<>();

    public static void add(File file) {
        files.add(file);
    }

    public static boolean containsLibraries() {
        RuntimeMXBean runtimeMxBean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
        String[] classpaths = runtimeMxBean.getClassPath().split(System.getProperty("path.separator"));

        List<File> classpathfiles = new LinkedList<>();
        for(String string : classpaths) classpathfiles.add(new File(string));

        for(File file : files) {
            if(!classpathfiles.contains(file)) return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static String getNewClassPaths() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        RuntimeMXBean runtimeMxBean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
        builder.append(runtimeMxBean.getClassPath());

        for(File file : files) {
            if(builder.length() > 0) builder.append(System.getProperty("path.separator"));

            builder.append(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }

        return builder.toString();
    }

    public static boolean restartWithLibrary(Class<?> main, String[] args) throws IOException {
        if(containsLibraries()) return false;

        List<String> runc = new LinkedList<>();

        runc.add(System.getProperty("java.home") + "\\bin\\javaw.exe");

        RuntimeMXBean runtimeMxBean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
        List<String> arguments = runtimeMxBean.getInputArguments();
        runc.addAll(arguments);

        File me = new File(LibLoader.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());

        String classpaths = getNewClassPaths();
        if(!classpaths.isEmpty()) {
            runc.add("-cp");
            runc.add(classpaths);
        }

        if(me.isFile()) {
            runc.add("-jar");
            runc.add(me.getAbsolutePath().replace("%20", " "));
        } else {
            runc.add(main.getName());
        }

        for(String arg : args) runc.add(arg);

        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(runc);
        processBuilder.directory(new File("."));
        processBuilder.redirectOutput(Redirect.INHERIT);
        processBuilder.redirectError(Redirect.INHERIT);
        processBuilder.redirectInput(Redirect.INHERIT);
        Process process = processBuilder.start();

        try {
            process.waitFor();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Hope someone has a better solution.

Comment: what is the issue here? what error do you get? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Currently I get no errors. But I want to add classpaths at runtime, without restart my jar. And to cast the systemclassloader to urlclassloader and add the urls not work anymore

Comment: Create a new classloader?

Comment: Problem is, the classes must be found my the systemclassloader not by a new classloader. So I must to replace the systemclassloader with my own and I think this doesn't work

Comment: Depends... there is the [`java.system.class.loader` property](https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemClassLoader%28%29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Problem is, the classes must be found my the system `ClassLoader` not by a new `ClassLoader`.

It sound like your current solution of relaunching the JVM is the only clean way to do it.

The system `ClassLoader` cannot be changed, and you cannot add extra JARs to it at runtime.

(If you tried to use reflection to mess with the system classloader's data structures, at best it will be non-portable and version dependent.  At worst it will be either error prone ... or blocked by the JVM's runtime security mechanisms.)

The solution suggested by Johannes Kuhn in a comment won't work.  The `java.system.class.loader` property is consulted during JVM bootstrap.  By the time your application is running, making changes to it will have no effect.  I am not convinced that the approach in his [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61442514/139985) would work either.

---

Here is one possible alternative way to handle this ... if you can work out what the missing JARs are early enough.

Write yourself a Launcher class that does the following:

- Save the command line arguments
- Find the application JAR file
- Extract the Main-Class and Class-Path attributes from the MANIFEST.MF.
- Work out what the real classpath should be based on the above ... and other application specific logic.
- Create a new `URLClassLoader` with the correct classpath, and the system classloader as its parent.
- Use it to load the main class.
- Use reflection to find the main classes `main` method.
- Call it passing the save command line arguments.

This is essentially the approach that Spring Bootstrap and OneJar (and other things) take to handle the "jars in a jar" problem and so on.  It avoids launching 2 VMs.

Comment: This is plain wrong. Did you even read my comments and followed the link there? I did change the system class loader in the past (last week, Java 14), and it did work good enough for my case.

Comment: But you didn't do it while the JVM was running!  That's what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: Yeah, changing the wheels of a running car is next to impossible. F1 still makes the cars come to a stop to do it. But I don't get why you don't want to restart your VM once with the right parameters to be able to do some adjustments later.

Comment: Well that is what the first line of my answer says!   And Yes I did read your comment and the link, and that approach won't work here unless you are suggesting that he writes a custom loader to replace the system classloader which allows you to update the classpath on the fly.  (And that has some scary implications for runtime type security.)

Comment: It's seems to me that the best solution is to restart the VM with the rights parameters.
Thanks for helping :)

Comment: Of course you can provide a custom class loader passing the class name as a `-Djava.syatem.class.loader` option which will properly pick up the class loader.

Comment: I don't think that helps.  A classloader that attempted to "define" the same class twice is probably going to fail.  (It ought to, because if it doesn't you would be breaking JVM runtime type security.)  So adding new JARs to a classloader  in order to alter the "meaning" of a previously loaded class is liable to not work.